# Eclipse “Error: Could not find or load main class” after renaming package

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse seems to not find the main class after I renamed the package

I tried to clean the project and every other solution found in stack overflow but they didn't work

I can manually run it using the `cmd` but eclipse can't run the program

Comment: Does your `main()` method with proper signature - `public static void main(String[] agrs)`? And dose your `main()` method in a public class?

Comment: @Razib yes i manage to run it using the cmd manually

Comment: Check the *Run Configurations* for your eclipse project and make sure the *Main class:* field points to your newly-renamed main class.

Comment: Look at your ["run" configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-12.htm). That should point to the correct class. And you shouldn't just rename a class, you need to use the refactoring dialog for that.

Comment: import package name  in main class

Comment: @pathfinderelite it point to the main with the new package name, i didn't rename the class but the package's name

Comment: The class name contains the package name: if the class is named Foo and is in the package com.bar, the class name is com.bar.Foo.

Comment: How did you rename the package name? Within eclipse?

Comment: @Jägermeister yes i rename it within eclipse and it said some warning that things might not work afterward because it contains a main

Answer (score 1):

I think some corrupted setting is already been in `metadata` directory in your workspace. Notice `metadata` is a hidden directory, if your are using ubuntu/linux then the directory name would be `.metadata`. Try to remove the `.metadata` directory.

Or you may remove the run configuration from **Run>Run Configuration**